# react native-undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.CookieManager.get')

Tags: react-native

undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.CookieManager.get')

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.CookieManager.get')
```

this error is shown on android emulator.
in react.js

```
    CookieManager.get("http://10.42.0.1:8000/login/", (err, res) => {

      fetch("http://10.42.0.1:8000/login/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-CSRFToken': res.csrftoken,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: 'user',
          password: 'securepassword',
        })
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
      })
    });
  }
```

pacakge.json

```
 "dependencies": {
"babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "0.47.1",
"react-native-cookie": "^0.2.0",
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
  },
"devDependencies": {
"babel-jest": "20.0.3",
"jest": "20.0.4",
"react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
 },
```

what I have done step by step:-

install library from npm

```
npm install react-native-cookie --save
```

link native code

```
react-native link react-native-cookie
```

here imported in app.js

```
import {
 Cookie,
  CookieManager
 } from 'react-native-cookie';
```

[image]

Any suggestions are welcomed.. we are sucked PLEASE HELP to get out of this !!!

Comment: Did you rebuild using `react-native run-android` after linking `react-native-cookie`? After modifying anything on the native side of development, a reload (R, R) will not do. That only refreshes `Javascript`.

Comment: @MattyK14 Yes. Absolutly rebuild whole project. still it seems to be error.

Comment: It looks like there is no CookieManager export in `react-native-cookie`. Only the Cookie is exported and it has the get method: https://github.com/shimohq/react-native-cookie#get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [README](https://github.com/shimohq/react-native-cookie#react-native-cookie) of the package before using it

There is nothing like CookieManager , its only Cookie .

Change CookieManager to Cookie.

Comment: yes it does not show this error now, but also not showing any response on screen as well as on django server.

Comment: @mayureshpatil The question was not about that.I request you to post new question regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

For me changing

`import {CookieManager} from '@react-native-community/cookies';`

to

`import CookieManager from '@react-native-community/cookies';`

resolved this problem.